# Cypher to connect matched nodes based on specific relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

If I do:

```
MATCH (x:NODE {x.name: "Node1"})-[r:REL1]-(y:NODE) return x,r,y
```

How do I then find all the `REL1` relationships amongst the set of `x` and `y` nodes?

EDIT:

Based on the answers I think the question wasn't clear.

Example graph:

```
create (:T1 {name:1}), (:T1 {name:2}), (:T1 {name:3}), (:T1 {name:4}), (:T1 {name:5}), (:T1 {name:6}), (:T1 {name:7})
match (a:T1 {name:1}), (b:T1 {name:2}) create (a)-[r:REL1]->(b)
match (a:T1 {name:1}), (b:T1 {name:3}) create (a)-[r:REL1]->(b)
match (a:T1 {name:5}), (b:T1 {name:4}) create (a)-[r:REL1]->(b)
match (a:T1 {name:5}), (b:T1 {name:3}) create (a)-[r:REL1]->(b)
match (a:T1 {name:5}), (b:T1 {name:2}) create (a)-[r:REL1]->(b)
match (a:T1 {name:5}), (b:T1 {name:1}) create (a)-[r:REL1]->(b)
match (a:T1 {name:7}), (b:T1 {name:6}) create (a)-[r:REL2]->(b)
match (a:T1 {name:7}), (b:T1 {name:5}) create (a)-[r:REL2]->(b)
match (a:T1 {name:7}), (b:T1 {name:4}) create (a)-[r:REL2]->(b)
match (a:T1 {name:7}), (b:T1 {name:3}) create (a)-[r:REL2]->(b)
```

I'm going to find everything that has a `REL1` relationship with node `name:5`. I want to also find all the `REL1` relationships amongst the returned nodes.

So I should get

```
5->4
5->3
5->2
5->1
1->2
1->3
```

But not

```
7->5
7->4
7->3
```

Because those are `REL2` relationships.

So I think I can do it like this:

```
match (a:T1 {name: 5})-[b:REL1]->(c:T1) return a,b,c
union match (a:T1)-[b:REL1]-(c:T1) return a,b,c
```

But the problem is that the graph I'm working with is really large, so this seems quite inefficient. I'd prefer to be able to

1. Select a set of nodes (everything connected to `5`)
2. Find all the connections amongst those nodes

Comment: `x.name` cannot be used that way, since a property name cannot contain a period -- unless you use back-ticks to quote the name. Did you mean to use `name` instead? And what do you mean by "amongst the set of x and y nodes"? Do you want to get all the `REL1` relationships between each distinct `x` and `y` pair?

Comment: sorry about the x.name that was just a mistake.

Comment: @cybersam  "Do you want to get all the REL1 relationships between each distinct x and y pair?" - yes. i think the use of union in my example is even wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to find out all the REL1 relationships amongst the set of x and y nodes then remove the condition from x node.

```
MATCH (x:NODE)-[r:REL1]-(y:User) return x,r,y
```

Comment: This query does not find *only* `REL1` relationships.

Answer (score 0):

We are correctly using Bi-Directional, to find the relationship either ways, but you are selecting only one relationship REL1, when you trying to find all the relationship remove the label from the relationship [], So you can use the below query and return *, it will return all the variables used.

```
MATCH (x:NODE {x.name: "Node1"})-[r]-(y:NODE) return *
```

Comment: The question distinctly says `REL1` relationships are wanted.

Answer (score 0):

To get all the distinct node pairs connected by one or more `REL1` relationships, just do this:

```
MATCH (a:T1)-[:REL1]->(c:T1)
RETURN DISTINCT a, c
```

The result would be:

```
╒══════════╤══════════╕
│"a"       │"c"       │
╞══════════╪══════════╡
│{"name":1}│{"name":2}│
├──────────┼──────────┤
│{"name":1}│{"name":3}│
├──────────┼──────────┤
│{"name":5}│{"name":1}│
├──────────┼──────────┤
│{"name":5}│{"name":2}│
├──────────┼──────────┤
│{"name":5}│{"name":3}│
├──────────┼──────────┤
│{"name":5}│{"name":4}│
└──────────┴──────────┘
```

If you also want the relationship(s) between each pair, you can do this:

```
MATCH (a:T1)-[r:REL1]->(c:T1)
RETURN a, c, COLLECT(r) AS rels
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. It doesn't seem to be what I was after - I want to get all the REL1 relationships amongst the resultant nodes after doing this query: `MATCH (a:T1 {name: 5})-[r:REL1]->(c:T1)`

Comment: Then you can just use that `MATCH` clause instead of mine.

Comment: That doesn't work. In the example data above if I run `MATCH (a:T1 {name: 3})-[r:REL1]-(c:T1) return a,r,c` it doesn't return the REL1 relationship between 1 and 5. The only thing I can get to work is this:
`match (a:T1 {name: 3})-[r:REL1]-(b:T1) set a.qu="1" set b.qu="1"` followed by 
`match p=(a:T1)-[:REL1]-(b:T1) where a.qu='1' and b.qu='1' return p` but this just seems like a silly way to be doing what feels like should be a routine task